# Variable triestatal

Tags: java, variables

Usando la clase Pruebas para probar un concepto en el que pensé:

```java
public class Pruebas {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Number number = new Number(2);

        // Ver si un número es positivo o negativo
        System.out.println(number.PositivoONegativo());
    }

}
```

Podemos observar que en la clase Number que creé, propondría introducir un nuevo tipo de variable en Java llamada variable triestatal. "boolean" existe, que es para variables de doble estado, pero si no me equivoco, no me he encontrado con variables triestatales, a menos que haya una clase de Java que ya implemente tal concepto.

```java
public class Number {

    private int dato;


    public Number(int dato) {
        this.dato = dato;
    }

    public int getDato() {
        return dato;
    }

    public void setDato(int dato) {
        this.dato = dato;
    }

    public int PositivoONegativo(){

        Number number0 = new Number(0);

        return this.equals(number0) ? 1: 0; // fix -> possible solution tristate variable
        /* if number0 == 0 -> return 0;
           if number0 > 0 -> return 1;
           if number0 < 0 -> return -1; 
                                        */
    }

}
```

Comment: O tal vez en vez de usar `boolean` usas `Boolean` y tienes `false`, `true` o `null`, puesto que como `Boolean` no es un primitivo es *nullable*. De todas maneras, si necesitas más de dos estados normalmente vale más la pena usar por ejemplo un Enum para poder ampliarlo cuanto quieras. Por algo se usan como "flag" muchas veces.

Comment: @Benito-B, pero al final aquí querría hacer un `false`, `true` o `zero`. Como una especie de FZ (Flag Zero)

Comment: Tres estados son tres estados. Si tú prefieres usar true, false y zero me parece bien, es tu decisión. Pero entonces, cual es la pregunta? Preguntas si hay alguna clase que sirva para determinar tres estados... existe, es `Boolean`. Por supuesto también podrías hacerlo con strings `"Estado1"`, `"Estado2"` y `"Estado3"`. Todo depende de cuánto tiempo quieras invertir en reinventar la rueda.

Comment: @Benito-B, creo que al final se trataría de un enum pero que esté forzado a tres estados. Acabo de leer dicha inspiración en https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/246742/best-datatype-to-store-a-ternary-or-three-state-variable. No obstante, entendido entonces, probaré a hacerlo con Boolean a ver qué sale exactamente además, ¡gracias!

Comment: Justo el ejemplo que planteas en la duda(el de devolver 0, 1 o -1) se resuelve con un método de Math llamado Sign, que te devuelve el signo del número que le introduces. Quizás eso te pueda servir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se podría resolver con un `Math.signum`, casteándolo a un `int`, dado que la función `Math.signum` devuelve `float` o `double` y la funcion `PositivoONegativo` devuelve un `int`.

```
public static int PositivoONegativo(int num){
   return (int) Math.signum(num);
}
```